# Access variables from partial in WebMatrix 2

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

Quite simply How can I pass from Partial to page on construction:

_SiteLayout.cshtml

```
@{PageData["phoneNumber"]="072342342343";}
```

Page.cshtml

```
 please call us on @PageData["phoneNumber"]
```

Ive tried things like this. What obvious step am I missing?

Its bring up blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use Session for this:

```
Session["phoneNumber"]="072342342343"

@Session["phoneNumber"]
```

Comment: Thanks that has done the trick. Do you have the document page link please, I cant find it. I want to read more about it.

Comment: I'll leave the question open to more answers, as I have to wait 23 hours before awarding bounty anyway. But your answer seems to be ideal. And doesnt use cookies(?) or other hack-arounds. It just seems more Global than I had thought. As opposed to a variable accessed on a page level, its on a session level. Or maybe Im thinking wrong. Anyway it works, and is stable(?) so thanks. Expect bounty award soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `HttpContext.Items` collection. It works about the same as the `Session`, but the collection is only kept alive for the duration of the request. I'm not sure how to most easily access it using Razor though. Read more about HttpContext.Items [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx).

Comment: Thats the per page kind of thing I expected Where by you are basically passing information between partials in the one request rather than between requests. I think I tried at one point though. I'll test it in a while and get back to you. :)

Comment: Using `HttpContext.Current.Items["test"]` It doesn't work. I just get blanks.

Comment: @Doomsknight I'm not that familiar with Web Matrix or cshtml in general. I think the problem is related to the order of events in the page processing. I believe the page is processed before the layout page sets the value. This would explain why both `PageData` and `HttpContext.Current.Items` are failing to provide the data you want. This also means that the `Session` based solution probably fails on the first request. Sorry, I won't be able help further...

Comment: Yep. Getting it to reverse is easy, as you can just create a normal parameter. I thought it might be an issue, need to check this first request concept out. No worries. +1 for trying :) Edit: your absolutely right on the first request. Hmmm. - I wonder if I should justput it in the webconfig file. And read from there.

Comment: @Doomsknight If the sole reason for this is to make the phone number available on all pages, a web config AppSettings entry would fit the bill. Or you could store it in the Application scope when the application starts (assuming there is a Global.asax or something similar in WebMatrix) and then get it from there in all the different pages where it is needed.